# How to represent data graphically in which a respondents can choose more than one group?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I am analyzing a survey in which one of the questions was (What is the industry segment of your company?) and the respondents can choose more than one category. I have used a pie chart to represent that data but then I thought this is not very accurate, since one company can choose more than one option. Any suggestion on what can I do to improve the representation?

Comment: You could used a Venn Diagram with a segment for each category, so that information about overlapping / intersecting responses will be preserved.